# Value not passed in Facebook API

Tags: facebook

I used the Facebook Feed Dialog.

My problem is If i calling the Feed API, the API is called but parameter is not passed.

```
FB.ui({

method: 'feed', 

  caption: 'Posted from Student tutorial Website',

  description: '<?PHP echo $postrow['description']; ?>'

}, function(response){});
```

Here caption and description value is not passed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a `feed` method according to the newest JS SDK docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui/

Do you mean https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: LOL! Nice that they forgot to add that in the JS SDK docs :-/

Comment: Sorry i can't understand what i forgot to add

Comment: Not you, FB doesn't show the feed dialog as an option in the docs I linked.